# Strange iOS 5 FetchedResultsController Predicate issue

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This code works fine on iOS 6, but doesn't return any results on iOS 5. The date is set to today with a category method. Can anyone spot anything weird? Thanks!

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"KSJob"];

NSLog(@"today: %@", [NSDate today]);

// We only want to show upcoming jobs.
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduledOn > %@", [NSDate today]]];

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"scheduledOn" ascending:YES]];
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                managedObjectContext:[(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]managedObjectContext]                                                 sectionNameKeyPath:@"dateToStringForSectionTitles"
                                                                           cacheName:@"UpcomingJobs"];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

NSDate category method:

```
+ (NSDate*) today
{
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];
    components.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    components.hour = 0;
    components.minute = 0;

    NSDate *today = [cal dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[[NSDate alloc] init] options:0];    
    return today;
}
```

Comment: Where is the sectionNameKeyPath? Also, did you make sure the NSManagedObjectContext you pass is a valid one?

Comment: The sectionNameKeyPath is in a category I made to section things by date. If I comment out the predicate in iOS 5 I get some data back. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post your [NSDate today] implementation to save our time to write it ?

Comment: Sure. Updated the question with it.

Comment: are you getting a valid context?

Comment: The context is valid.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found it. It doesn't seem to be inserting anything for those date fields on iOS 5 for some reason. That explains a lot though.